# Can you setup a whitelist for allowed files in Amazon CloudFront

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I'm using CloudFront as a CDN, and my website as an origin for pulls.  Basically, I have *cdn.mydomain.com* pointing over to Cloudfront, and Cloudfront pulls any requests from *www.mydomain.com*.  However, I don't want users to be able to request things like *cdn.mydomain.com/default.aspx* or *cdn.mydomain.com/Robots.txt*.  In fact, I only want to serve up images, JavaScript files, CSS stylesheets, and other static content.

What I've figured out is somewhat of a hack, though it appears to work.  I set the Default behavior to point to an Origin called *Null*.  The *Null* origin points to *null.mydomain.com* which doesn't exist, thus any request will just error out.  Then, I setup other behaviors for each directory in my website that I want to whitelist.  It looks like this:

[image]

This appears to work, but is there a better, less hacky solution that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a less hacky approach is to just put your static files into an S3 bucket and use the S3 bucket as the origin pull.  Leave your webserver out of it altogether.